# Почему не работает translateY при открытии модального окна?

Tags: css, css3

Сверстал мобильную версию и для неё решил сделать модальные окна с анимацией. При открытии модального окна оно должно быть за пределами оверлея при помощи `transform: translateY(100%)`, но почему-то при рендеринге модального окна `translateY` не работает. Если перевернуть устройство или переключить вкладки или вернуться снова, то свойство `translateY` применится. Почему оно не применяется при рендеринге?

Стили оверлея модального окна:

```
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
z-index: 10001;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-height: 100%;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overscroll-behavior: contain;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Стили модального окна (дочерний элемент оверлея):

```
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
background: #fff;
transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
height: 100%;
transform: translateY(100%);
max-height: 100%;
```